# Using #define with switch state in C

Tags: c, switch-statement, c-preprocessor

I'm not sure why I'm not allowed to do this. Can someone explain to how to get around the compilation error. I'm new to C, came from Java.

*error: expected ':' or '...' before ';' token*

```
#define NORTH 1;

int main (void){
switch (functionCallThatReturnsAnInt()){
    case NORTH : //compile time error here
        printf("NORTH");
        break;
    case 2 : // no compile time error
        printf("2");
        break;
    //removed rest to reduce clutter
    }
}

int functionCallThatReturnsAnInt(void){
    return NORTH;
}
```

Comment: `#define NORTH 1;` --> `#define NORTH 1`

Comment: `#define NORTH 1`. No semicolon.

Comment: `#define` does text substitution. Everything after the identifier to the end of the line is copied verbatim. So after preprocessing, the line `case NORTH :` becomes `case 1; :`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For future viewers:

As noted above by @PSkocik and @BLUEPIXY when using define leave off the semicolon.

Instead of

```
#define NORTH;
```

Use

```
#define NORTH
```